# TCPDF 2 columns same amount of text?

Tags: php, pdf, dynamic-data, tcpdf

Hi I'm using tcpdf to generate a dynamic pdf for an e-zine i work for. But i have a problem, When i write the body text, I need to have the same amount of text per column and i use 2 of them. It writes my html text perfectly including images and everything, but at the end it doesn't align the text of both columns...

I'm new to tcpdf and i don't have any ideas where to start looking for a solution... any ideas how can i do this?

I'm using this function to write the text, a correction or a mockup for a solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * Print chapter body
 * @param $file (string) name of the file containing the chapter body
 * @param $mode (boolean) if true the chapter body is in HTML, otherwise in simple text.
 * @public
 */
 public function PartBody($text, $mode=false) {
     $this->selectColumn();
 // get esternal file content
 $content = $text;
 // set font
 $this->SetFont('times', '', 9);
 $this->SetTextColor(50, 50, 50);
 // print content
 if ($mode) {
      // ------ HTML MODE ------
      $this->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, 'J');
 } else {
      // ------ TEXT MODE ------
      $this->Write(0, $content, '', 0, 'J', true, 0, false, true, 0);
 }

 $this->Ln();
 }
```

Comment: can i see the $content code please? The 'J' stands for Justified, so if you want it left aligned it has to be 'L'. but it is difficult to guess without seeing your outcome